# Why did Irene stealthily take Jerome's hair to the test centre when she knew he was a Valid?

Tags: gattaca

In *Gattaca* (1997), why did Irene stealthily take Jerome's hair to the test centre when she knew he was a Valid (at that moment)? Why did Irene look so disappointed when she saw the test result? What does the phrase "Quite a catch" mean?

Comment: Welcome.  These are good questions - however as others have commented, you can split this into multiple questions here.

Comment: @iandotkelly "These are good questions", you say. Are they? https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask says that a user should "thoroughly search for an answer before asking your question". There are plenty of sites out there that offer an in-depth analysis of Gattaca which would likely answer most or all of these questions -- most of which aren't even caused by "not understanding conversations due to lack of English skills". Q1 for instance is answered by https://gattaca.fandom.com/wiki/Irene_Cassini , found by googling https://www.google.com/search?q=gattaca+irene+jerome+hair .

Comment: @BCdotWEB .... this is a new contributor, I'm trying to address the biggest concern of the question

Comment: @BCdotWEB the link does not explain, it just repeated what I already wrote in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes me want to see the film again, after so many years. Its definitely a favorite of mine.

> why did Irene stealthily take Jerome's hair to the test centre when she knew he was a Valid (at that moment)?

She wanted to find out just **how** perfect he is. She is told this from his score - 9.3 - given by the testing center. She knows her own score is a lot lower.

She is disappointed because, despite her modification, she is still pretty much a second rate citizen (due to suggestion of impending heart failure, and that she is on heart medication) and she is actually really interested in Jerome, but - with someone so high on the 'perfect' scale - **why** would he want to be with her?

She is disappointed because she is **sure** that she will be rejected by her perceived superior. That is why later, she offers her hair to him, so he can see what number she comes up as and he can decide whether she is too low for him to date, or yet still be interested.

> What does the phrase "Quite a catch" mean?

"someone who is a good person to have a relationship with or to marry because they are rich, attractive etc"; a person considered highly desirable to have a relationship with.

ie. the friends of my then-girlfriend told her that I was quite the catch. My now-wife has never forgiven them.

I had answers for the other questions in progress:

which will be replied to later as the questions arise...

References from:  https://imsdb.com/scripts/Gattaca.html

Edit:

- recommend a read as it is an earlier draft of the script that shows a lot more of the situation with regards to the Valids themselves, as well as other questions that may arise.

Comment: I had this question in the beginning of the movie because I don't think Irene had an attraction to Vicent and I don't know that Valids have different levels, I thought Valids would treat each others equally. But why does Irene have heart problem if she is a valid? Heart problem would be the first thing to be eleminated for selected births

Comment: ah, that was one of your other questions - if you post it I'll add my answer to that. I think I would get a spank if I answered all your questions in one post... But in reference to the first part, no its clear the valids themselves are not treated equally in their society. Its a bit of an echo of our civilization, regardless of what we strive to do, to make ourselves perfect, the basic human problems remain. As for attraction, no, it is not clear, its left as subtle interest, glances, catching a look. Nothing so obviously animalist that an in-valid would make (See Vincent's behaviour)

Comment: ok, so you mean it is not clear that Valids are treated equally and it is also not clear Irene had attraction to Vincent in the beginning of the film. I don't get this from your comment : "Nothing so obviously animalist that an in-valid would make (See Vincent's behaviour)". Could you make this point more clearly?

Comment: Ah no, I think you misread my comment (I had reached the comment limit). It is clear that valids are not treated equally. Irene is a valid but will never go to space, likewise Jeromes colleague Napoleon is a valid but will never go to space either. Valids, at inception, have base human aspects removed, those parts make us near animal, to eliminate issues such as alcoholism, addiction, violence, obesity, etc, so the adult valid is a more often muted, restrained, health-conscious version of us. [see next comment]

Comment: @Dat - Vincent, as a fraudulent valid is doing everything the real valids fear to do: he drinks alcohol, he eats frequently at a decadent restaurant, eats a lot of juicy steaks, smokes before exercise, etc. All the real valids around him are incredulous, and jealous.  Jerome also chases Irene and is not afraid to throw a punch. He is behaving like a normal human, an invalid.

Comment: where do you watch all Vincent's activities such as eating a lot of juicy steaks, smoking before exercise...and all the real valids around him are incredulous, and jealous...in the movies? Napoleon did not appear in the film neither. I still don't know who Napoleon is.

Comment: @Dat - apologies - since I didn't have a copy of the film to watch at hand, I had to go by memory and the draft version of the script I linked to in my answer. I have clarified the link to make it clear there is more to read in it that makes it clearer than in the movie. However, unfortunately my comments are referencing that version and not the final movie, which explains the missing colleague, smoking scene, steak scene, etc. Worth a read, it might make what did end up in the movie a bit clearer.

Comment: Back to the valids not being treated equally, in the movie there is a line from the Director: "But now, there are enough of the right kind of people to warrant a new measuring stick." - Indicating that within this new elite, just being a valid is not enough, they had to devise a new way of measuring this sub-group of humanity; to find the best (Jerome/Eugene), and remove the worst, and reassign the not as good (Irene)." Earlier when Irene questions being reassigned from her normal job, the Director replies "Your place is assured" (ie. whatever she does, her genetics have fixed her place).

Comment: the film only does not have enough scenes to help me understand, I need to read film script to understand more

Comment: @Dat The early draft is the only easily available version of the script free on line. There also transcripts but they have less detail. Because I had not seen the film for years, the draft script was the only version to go on, and my memories of it. What is interesting is how much of the early draft is retained in the final film (which I do now have access to).

Answer (score 3):

The film's [original script](https://sfy.ru/?script=gattaca) gives us some additional info. Irene is trying to work out if she's even close to being in his league.

> TECHNICIAN (remarking on the profile result) 9.4...very nice.
>
> Irene does not appear to share the technician's enthusiasm.
> She emerges from the sequencing lab and enters her car.  Taking
> a palm-top computer from her purse, she inserts the disc into
> the computer.  Jerome's counterfeit genetic profile appears on
> the screen.  The details confirm her worst fears.

After their date she explains that she's not good enough for him. Whatever her score is, it isn't a 9.4, which is basically the score of [a superior human](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/100979/valorum).

> Irene turns to Jerome.
>
> IRENE: (blurting out what's really on her mind) --Listen, I don't want to waste your time and I really don't want you to waste mine. I don't know what you're after but I have a feeling I'm not it.

According to Jerome, this is a pretty common occurrence nowadays.

> **EUGENE:** (teasing) *You are a catch.  No doubt she's worried that she would lower the standard of your offspring. Everybody wants to "breed up".*